Nav2 global costmap error No map received
I have ROS2 with humble and currently trying to implement
https://docs.nav2.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html
into my own robot in simulation. I have a working robot_localization setup so far.
I am able to get local costmap but I am not able to visualize the global costmap in rviz2
i get the "No map Received" Warning and the topic's data is only -1
Nav2 parameters for global and local costmap:

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.44
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 20
        max_obstacle_height: 3.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:
          topic: /camera/points
          max_obstacle_height: 3.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      robot_radius: 0.44
      resolution: 0.1
      rolling_window: True
      width: 50
      height: 50
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:
          topic: /camera/points
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          raytrace_max_range: 100.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 100.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
    ```


